# New to javascript, and can't figure out matching document.getElementById to value in an if statement

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to figure out how to change the colour of the container div by using a javascript toggle button, but I think I am missing something obvious when trying to get the div to work in the statement. When I run the code and press the toggle button nothing happens. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <style>

    body {

    }

    #container {
        height: 300px;
        width: 500px;
        background: lightblue;
        position: absolute;
        float: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    #button {
        font-size: 30px;

    }
    </style>

    <script>

    function toggleColour()

    {
        if (document.getElementById('container').style.background == ("lightblue"))
            {
                document.getElementById('container').style.background = ("orange");
            }
        else
            {
                document.getElementById('container').style.background = ("lightblue");
            }
    }

    </script>

    <body>
    <div id="container">

    <h1>Lets button this up!</h1>
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="toggleColour()">Toggle Colour</button>

    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Press it a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. `background` is a shorthand CSS property that combines many background properties together ([see the list here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)). If you set the background color using just `background` you still need to read the result from `background-color` (and you should use that in the CSS as well if it's the only background property you're setting).
2. `lightblue` and `orange` are also shorthands for RGB codes. Most browsers (if not all?) return the RGB values (e.g. `rgb(173, 216, 230)` for `lightblue`) even if the color is set using the color's name.
3. `.style` in JavaScript doesn't return styles applied by CSS, only those applied directly with the element's style attribute. You need to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) instead.

In this case it'd be much simpler to just assume the background color's starting status and use a flag to keep track of it.

```
var bg = 'lightblue';

function toggleColour()
{
    if( bg === "lightblue" ) 
    {
        bg = "orange";
    }
    else
    {
        bg = "lightblue";
    }

    document.getElementById('container').style.background = bg;
}
```

Note that you don't need parentheses around string literals and it's good form to use the strict `===` for comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked perfectly. I will make sure to the === in future for comparison. Thank you as well Bergi. I am especially thankful for all of the corrections to my other mistakes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the [`.style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) only does reflect the `style` attribute of the element (which is empty), not all the styles that are applied on it via CSS. Therefore, on the first click the `.style.background` is empty, and will be set to an explicit `"lightblue"` (which you don't see). On the second click, it is set now and satisfies the if-condition so that it will be changed to `"orange"`.

What you can do:

- Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) to get the actual value. Yet, it initially would be `rgb(173, 216, 230)` not `lightblue` so a cross-browser solution is not easy.
- Just swap the condition: If it is orange then set it to blue, else (if it is blue or nothing) set it to orange. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9jj4/1/))
- Set the `style` attribute to a start value in the HTML ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9jj4/2/))

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi is right. To get the resulting style for an element (come it from CSS or from inline style) you would use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) with real browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and IE9) and `currentStyle` with IE prior to version 9.